# problem with screen brightness

Tags: 13.04, brightness

I'am using Ubuntu 13.04 on Lenovo G500 -E

when i turn my laptop computer on the brightness of screen is 0 and i need to increase the brightness to see the screen

is this problem related to Ubuntu 13.04?

please help me to solve this problem

thanks in advance,

Comment: Not 13.04-specific; I installed 13.04 on three different Lenovos including a T500 without this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to login and set the brightness via the brightness control.

Or you can try if it works with this terminal command

> echo 1666 >> /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness

if this works you can add this command to the **/etc/rc.local** file which will run this command at startup process.

ps. you can change 1666 to whatever you want (more or less brightness)

Comment: your answer is true but we need to add `sleep 5` (or more, or less) a line above the echo ...-line ,because `/etc/rc.local` is executed before the screen is fully initialized